# using a constructor to spawn a drawimage

Tags: javascript

I am having an issue using a constructor to spawn my drawimage. I need to spawn rows and rows of these so I need to be able to spawn these easily. so far I cannot fix this. the error I am recieving right now is Uncaught ReferenceError: requestAnimFrame is not defined 
Any thoughts on how I can fix this to make the parameter work? I need to have the propertyName equals out to like y1,y2,y2 and so forth because this is how I set the y of the blocks.

```
enemy.y = rand;
enemy.y2 = rand2;
enemy.y3 = rand3;
enemy.y4 = rand4;
enemy.y5 = rand5;
enemy.y6 = rand6;
enemy.y7 = rand7;
enemy.y8 = rand8;
enemy.y9 = rand9;
```

so here is the code that comes before the enemy.y1-y9's.

```
var requestAnimFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||   window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;

window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimFrame

function drawPiece(x,y,letter){
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
 this.letter = letter;
 var propertyName = propertyName;
 this.spawn = function(){
  for(var i = 1; i <= 9; i++){
    if(i > 1){
      var propertyName = this.letter + i;
    }
      context.drawImage(imgs[0],enemy.x,enemy[propertyName], tileWidth, tileHeight);
  }
}

enemy.propertyName = rand;
requestAnimFrame(drawPiece);
check();
}
var redblk = new drawPiece(900,rand,"y");
```

EDIT: now the error is gone. Do I have enough in the constructor for this to work, seeing this piece of code? Because there is no errors but there is no blocks appearing.

Comment: I don't think such error could be thrown with just this snippet of code. The `requestAnimFrame` is definitely declared (and also has a non-undefined value - ***tested*** this in Chrome). So the problem could be somewhere else (such as somewhere ***before*** this snippet of code).

Comment: I don't think it pertains to the specific bug you are experiencing, but you may want to check this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame

Looking at your declaration, I don't think requestAnimFrame will pass the parameters that drawPiece expects.

Comment: now the error is gone. Do I have enough in the constructor for this to work, seeing this piece of code? Because there is no errors but there is no blocks appearing? Also added this as an edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the complete semantics of your code, but I think you need to change:

```
...
requestAnimFrame(drawPiece);
...
var redblk = new drawPiece(900,rand,"y");
```

For this:

```
var redblk = new drawPiece(900,rand,"y");
requestAnimFrame(redblk.spawn);
```

However, the context for the callback on 'spawn' may be wrong I'm thinking (would have to be verified, but I believe 'this' in the callback would point to window, not redblk).

You may want to change:

```
function drawPiece(x,y,letter){
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
 this.letter = letter;
 var propertyName = propertyName;
 this.spawn = function(){
  for(var i = 1; i <= 9; i++){
    if(i > 1){
      var propertyName = this.letter + i;
    }
      context.drawImage(imgs[0],enemy.x,enemy[propertyName], tileWidth, tileHeight);
  }
}
```

For this:

```
function drawPiece(x,y,letter){
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
 this.letter = letter;
 var propertyName = propertyName; //Is the RHS of this assignment properly defined?
 var ThisClosure = this;
 this.spawn = function(){
  for(var i = 1; i <= 9; i++){
    if(i > 1){
      var propertyName = ThisClosure.letter + i;
    }
      context.drawImage(imgs[0],enemy.x,enemy[propertyName], tileWidth, tileHeight);
  }
}
```

However, have you considered returning a function with the parameters in its closure instead?

Something like this would be more elegant if you don't need to change the passed parameters afterwards:

```
function drawPiece(x,y,letter){
 //x, y and letter are defined in the closure of the returned function.
 //judging by your use of it, propertyName is probably defined in the closure as well
 return(function(){
  for(var i = 1; i <= 9; i++){
    if(i > 1){
      var propertyName = letter + i;
    }
      context.drawImage(imgs[0],enemy.x,enemy[propertyName], tileWidth, tileHeight);
  });
}

requestAnimFrame(drawPiece(900,rand,"y"));
```